# Why isn't my ng-controller being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to familiarize myself with Angular. So if this questions is incredibly simple, I apologize in advance. In my `index.html`, I'm trying to call one of the controllers to test out how Angular calls certain things.

In the code, I have `<div ng-controller="listCtrl">`. However, something as simple as `{{3+5}}` isn't being evaluated and being printed to the page as is. I've tried messing around with the `ng` attribute and when I have something like

```
<div ng-app="">
    {{3+5}}
</div>
```

it will work and print out 8. I was wondering if someone could take a look at the code (posted below) and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="turtleFacts">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <h3>Heading3
        <strong>QUIZ</strong>
        </h3>
</div>

<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
    {{dummyData}}
</div>

</div>

<!-- My application scripts -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/list.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My `list.js`:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module("turtleFacts")
        .controller("listCtrl", ListController);

    function ListController($scope) {
        $scope.dummyData = "hello world";
    }
})
```

And my `app.js`:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("turtleFacts", []);
})();
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
Project
 |
 +-- css
 |    
 +-- js
 |  |  
 |  +-- controllers
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- list.js
 |  | 
 |  +-- app.js
 |    
 +-- index.html
```

It's my assumption that the page should have "Hello World" but all I'm getting is `{{dummyData}}`. Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide that you may need. Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in your console? FYI, if you're going to use jQuery with Angular (not recommended), you should include jQuery first

Comment: @Phil I get `Argument 'listCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` which I guess is the root of the problem. Dont understand why it's not being called. Also thanks for the tip about jQuery/Angular.

Comment: I think, *maybe*, your app.js is running after list.js.  With the `[]` argument, that call will erase the module and re-create it.  This would erase the controller registration.

Comment: Ah, your `list.js` contains an IIFE without the "II". End it with `()`

Comment: @Amy Is it possible to force `app.js` to run before `list.js`?

Comment: The way you place <script> tag the js files will run

Comment: @Phil It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `list.js`, you forgot to add `();` at the end of your IIFE :)